# Get messages of a page from Facebook Opengraph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the messages sent to my Facebook page via the OpenGraph API. One solution I thought of is to use the `read_page_mailboxes` [1] but we got rejected by Facebook when we requested for this permission, this is because we don't really have an app where users login via Facebook.

To give more context the app is just a Facebook bot what I want to do is get all the messages that have been sent to the page and then get the facebook `user_id` of those user.

**Update**

Some of the comments below says why submit it for review if login is not required. My question would be how do add the `read_page_mailboxes` permission without submitting for review. Right now we're doing a request to `HTTP GET /<page_id>/conversations` and the response we get is:

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#279) Requires read_page_mailboxes permission to manage the    object",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 279,
  "fbtrace_id": "BHhMgQNCf4A"
 }
}
```

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-read_page_mailboxes

Comment: "we don't really have an app where users login via Facebook" - then why even send the permission to review? that does not make any sense.

Comment: If your app is not meant to be used by the general public, then you don’t need to send it for review.

Comment: @CBroe  Is there a way to add `read_page_mailboxes` without submitting for review?

Comment: You just ask for it they way you would ask for any other permission.