# Facebook Graph API "(#279) Requires read_page_mailboxes permission to manage the object"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This is the same as the question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376558/get-messages-of-a-page-from-facebook-opengraph-api) that never got answered. I have set the user roles as admin for the account I am trying to access the page with. 
How can I enable this without submitting for review? v2.12

Comment: I'd guess it may not be possible, you might just have to submit the app for review? (And posting a question again won't necessarily help you get an answer if it wasn't answered last time, sorry.) This is probably a question for Facebook themselves though, whether you can grant this permission to an incomplete app for testing, and it looks like the only point of contact is the [Facebook Support Developers Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers).

Comment: please add your code and a detailed description. did you authorize your admin account with the permission correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can have this permission with a App Developer permission accessing the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Unfortunately Facebook temporarily [closed the review of new applications](https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/104197713763517/). But as a small app developer (less than 10 registered users), you'll be able to

1. Select your application (You can not have "Graph API Explorer" selected)
2. Click on "Get Token"
3. then "Get User Access Token"
4. Select the "read_page_mailboxes"

When completing the registration, select your page in the "Get Token" button, and finally you can use this API with the generated token.